# Average number of records required to reach given number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to work out the average number of entries required to reach a given number. Think of it as a sales environment: each record in the database indicates a phone call has been made. There is a marker in one of the columns that indicates if a sale was made. I've created something that will return the number of entries required to reach a given number, however, I'd like it to 'reset' after it reaches that number then start counting again, and so on until all of the data has been checked.

The table looks like the below:

```
UID | DATE       | TIME     | NAME1 | SUBNAME1 | SUCCESS? |
1   | 01/01/2014 | 09:00:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
2   | 01/01/2014 | 09:01:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
3   | 01/01/2014 | 09:02:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
4   | 01/01/2014 | 09:03:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
5   | 01/01/2014 | 09:04:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
6   | 01/01/2014 | 09:05:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
7   | 01/01/2014 | 09:06:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
8   | 01/01/2014 | 09:07:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
9   | 01/01/2014 | 09:08:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
10  | 01/01/2014 | 09:09:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
11  | 01/01/2014 | 09:11:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
12  | 01/01/2014 | 09:12:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
13  | 01/01/2014 | 09:13:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 0        |
14  | 01/01/2014 | 09:14:00 | Test1 | SubTest1 | 1        |
```

If I wanted to know how many calls were required to reach three sales, my query would initially return 5. What I'd like to do is check the entire table and return the average - 7 in this case.

See below for my query thus far:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT UID, NAME1, SUBNAME1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SUCCESS = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
  OVER (ORDER BY UID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      AS RunningTotal
  FROM dev.dbo.t1
  WHERE Name1 = 'Test1'
  AND Subname1 = 'SubTest1'
)
SELECT count(*)+1 AS [Count]
FROM CTE
WHERE RunningTotal < 3
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)

Thanks

Comment: A sqlfiddle would help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average number of calls to reach 3, I think you can just count up the number of rows in the database, the number of successes.  The ratio is the average number of calls per success.  Three times this value is the average for three successes.

```
select count(*) as NumCalls, sum(Success) as Success,
       3.0 * count(*) / sum(Success) as AvgPer3
from dev.dbo.t1 t1;
```

This should be very close to what you want.  There might be small tweaks if you want to end on a success or on a third success.